# Unity animation (.anim) to 3ds max

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 3dsmax

I would like to know if 3ds max supports Unity's animation file .anim? I am trying to create like a program that makes it easier to animate and then you can get that animation file and import it to 3ds max. I have an idea to make a unity WRITE the python script of an animation but there should be an easier way of doing that.

Is there any way of importing animation from unity3d to 3ds max? Maybe we could convert .anim to some other extensions that 3ds max supports.

Looking forward to hear your ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a package called FBX exporter from package manager in Unity. Then you can export your models with animations as an FBX file which can be used in 3ds max. You can check out this [guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.fbx@2.0/manual/prefabs.html) if you are not sure how to use FBX exporter.

Comment: Oh, so that's how. Then I could use that model as a bone in 3ds max. But one more thing. Are there any alternative ways to get fbx exporter? Because in the country where I live it's impossible to get it (blocked).

Comment: If you have Unity installed then FBX exporter will be a part of it. You just need to enable it from Window>package manager. I am not sure if its available in the old Unity versions but Unity 2021 does have it.

Comment: That's awesome! I have unity 2021(dot something something). I will look into! Thanks a lot! I will reward you with 100 reps now 

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can export unity animations to 3ds max. You can even do multiple at once using a so-called FBX file.

Comment: How can I save created animations (created in unity) in fbx files if they are in .ani file?